# v-if and v-else not working because updating page every time

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button

I have the issue that the div in the v-if statement is not correctly working. If you run the server and the page when you click the button `Sign Up` it will briefly showing the div for signing up but it will get back the the original div in the first v-if statement after few seconds.

**Instead I expect that** it would show just show the div in the v-else because I am changing the boolean `showSignUp` with the `v-on:click="signUp"` which will call the function in the Vue App that will change the boolean.

This is the **HTML** :

```
<body onload="init()">
        <!-- using the Vue App -->
        <div id="app">
            <!-- If it is not signed in just make it sign -->
            <div v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Top Bar -->
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <h1>UST Computer Science Submission Tool</h1>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-end">
                    <div v-if="!showSignUp">
                        <form class="getSpace" > <!-- SIGN IN FORM -->
                            <!-- Input fields -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Buttons -->
                            <button v-on:click="signIn" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                            <button v-on:click="signUp" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                    <div v-if="showSignUp">
                        <form class="getSpace"> <!-- SIGN UP FORM -->
                            <!-- Input fields -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="singUpEmail">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="singUpInputPassword">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Buttons -->
                            <button v-on:click="submitRegistration" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Else is already signed in -->
            <div v-else class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">You did it</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This is the **JS** for the Vue App:

```
let app

// On loading page
function init() {
    app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isLoggedIn: false,
            showSignUp: false
        },
        methods: {
            signIn: signIn,
            signUp: signUp,
            submitRegistration: submitRegistration,
        }
    });
}

// methods
function signIn(event) { // when clicked Sing In button
    // check before in the data base if it is correct

    // Now show the Users page
    app.isLoggedIn = !app.isLoggedIn;
}

function signUp (event) { // when clicked Sing Up button
    // This will change the form
    console.log('was here');
    app.showSignUp = true;
}

function submitRegistration (event) {
    console.log(event);
    // Call http 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to prevent the action

```
<button v-on:click.prevent="signUp" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Or just add `type="button"`

Comment: It makes sense because it is a form, by default the action on button submits the form and so it refreshes the page. Preventing the default behaviour or changing button's type as Phil mentioned should fix the issue.